# Entity Framework - Code first - Data annotations - Unnecessary foreign key columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Entity Framework is creating two unnecessary columns in my AccountCompanyRole table.

**AccountCompany**

```
public class AccountCompany
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0), ForeignKey("Account")]
    public int AccountID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1), ForeignKey("Company")]
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }

    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AccountCompanyRole> AccountCompanyRoles { get; set; }
}
```

**AccountCompanyRoles**

```
public class AccountCompanyRole
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0), ForeignKey("AccountCompany")]
    public int AccountID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1), ForeignKey("AccountCompany")]
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2), ForeignKey("Role")]
    public int RoleID { get; set; }

    public virtual AccountCompany AccountCompany { get; set; }

    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

**OnModelCreating**

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<AccountCompanyRole>()
            .HasRequired(p => p.AccountCompany)
            .WithMany()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

**Result in DB**

[image: Result in DB]

As you can see, EF has added two extra foreign keys in AccountCompanyRoles even tho I specified primary key and foreign key in Data Annotations.

**Questions**

1. How do I prevent it from creating AccountCompany_AccountID and AccountCompany_CompanyID?
2. Is this the best structure for what I am after? Should I instead use one primarykey and put IsUnique index on AccountID and CompanyID? This would probably solve my problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the foreign keys in your fluent relationship like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AccountCompanyRole>()
            .HasRequired(p => p.AccountCompany)
            .WithMany().HasForeignKey(d => new { d.AccountID, d.CompanyID })
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<AccountCompany>()
            .HasMany(c => c.AccountCompanyRoles)
            .WithRequired(d => d.AccountCompany)
            .HasForeignKey(e => new {e.AccountID, e.CompanyID});
```

**Edit:**
Added fluent config for AccountCompany

Comment: I still get two extra columns in my AccountCompanyRole table. I even deleted DB/Migrations and recreated my DB but that didn't help either.

Comment: Try adding fluent config for your AccountCompany relationshis as well (see updated answer)

Comment: Thanks that was it :)

Answer (score 3):

> How do I prevent it from creating AccountCompany_AccountID and AccountCompany_CompanyID?

First, remove the `ForeignKey` attribute from `CompanyID` and `RoleID`.

Then either put `ForeignKey` attribute on your `AccountCompany` member like this:

```
public class AccountCompanyRole
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int AccountID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2), ForeignKey("Role")]
    public int RoleID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AccountID, CompanyID")]
    public virtual AccountCompany AccountCompany { get; set; }

    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

or use fluent configuration like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AccountCompanyRole>()
            .HasRequired(r => r.AccountCompany)
            .WithMany(c => c.AccountCompanyRoles)
            .HasForeignKey(r => new { r.AccountID, r.CompanyID })
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

> Is this the best structure for what I am after? Should I instead use one primarykey and put IsUnique index on AccountID and CompanyID? This would probably solve my problem..

IMO both are valid approaches, use the one that better suits your needs.

Comment: Hi! I tried both your suggestions with Data Annoitations and Fluent API and I still get two extra columns in my AccountCompanyRole Table. I even deleted DB/Migrations and recreated my DB but that didn't help either..

Comment: Had to add fluent config for AccountCompany aswell. However, I upvoted you for such a detailed answer. Thanks

Comment: @Reft You are welcome. Glad that your problem has been solved. However the "solution" smells. Configuring one and the same relation two times makes no sense. I've checked it in my EF environment, the problem was `WithMany()` call, it should be as in the updated answer.